# C# - HTTP Get run in parallel tasks randomly fails with: Error while copying content to stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task-parallel-library, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

In my C# application (.NET Core 3.1) there's an automatic task that every X hours starts another task, which gets run in parallel multiple times with different parameters.
At the end of this automatic task, there's a call to `await Task.WhenAll(tasksList).` to wait for parallel tasks completion.

Every task issues an *HTTPClient* (using IHttpClientFactory factory method) and issues a GET request, with the following syntax:

```
var res = await client.GetAsync(url);
if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  var exit = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  [...omitted]
}
```

The **issue** occurs randomly when two tasks, that share the same GET URL, run at a distance of max 60-70ms. Sometimes both tasks fail, one after another, each with this same exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ChunkedEncodingReadStream.CopyToAsyncCore(Stream destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent.SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task serializeToStreamTask, MemoryStream tempBuffer)
```

From the logs, I can see how two different HTTP Requests are correctly started and received by the server.

If I *remove the ReadAsStringAsync part*, the issue never occurs so I presume it's related to the *content reading* (after the status code check), almost as if the two tasks end sharing the Get result (while having two different active connections issued). I tried using a ReadAsStreamAsync but the issue still occurs (this helps to reduce the occurrence, although).

Another thing that could be related is that the result retrieved is quite heavy (the last time I downloaded it, it ended being a .json file of 4.5MB, more or less).

**Should I run each task sequentially? Or am I issuing the HTTP Requests wrong?**

IF you want to test this issue, here you can find the **source code** of a console app I'm using to reproduce the issue (if it doesn't occurs by the first 20calls, restart the app until it occurs):

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHttpClient();
                    services.AddTransient<TaskRunner>();
                }).UseConsoleLifetime();

            var host = builder.Build();
            using (var serviceScope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                    var x = services.GetRequiredService<TaskRunner>();
                    var result = await x.Run();

                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error Occured");
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }

        public class TaskRunner
        {
            private static IHttpClientFactory _httpFactory { get; set; }
            public TaskRunner(IHttpClientFactory httpFactory)
            {
                _httpFactory = httpFactory;
            }
            public async Task<string> Run()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting loop...");
                do
                {
                    await Task.Delay(2500); // wait app loading
                    await SendRequest();
                } while (true);
            }
            private static async Task SendRequest()
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { ExecuteCall(), ExecuteCall()};
            }
            private async static Task<bool> ExecuteCall()
            {
                try
                {
                    var client = _httpFactory.CreateClient();
                    // fake heavy API call (> 5MB data)
                    var api = "https://api.npoint.io/5896085b486eed6483ce";
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting call at " + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"));
                    var res = await client.GetAsync(api);
                    if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var exit = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        /* STREAM read alternative
                        var ed = await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                        using var sr = new StreamReader(ed);
                        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            result.Append(await sr.ReadLineAsync());
                        }
                        var exit = result.ToString();
                        */
                        Console.WriteLine(exit.Substring(0, 10));
                        //Console.WriteLine(exit);
                        
                        Console.WriteLine("Ending call at " + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"));
                        return true;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(res.StatusCode);
                        Console.WriteLine("Ending call at " + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"));
                    return false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // put breakpoint here
                    // Exception => called on line:78 but if content isn't read it never occurs
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help/suggestion you can give me!

Comment: The server may not allow two connection from same client simultaneously which is giving the error.  Not sure.  Or you are using the same port number with same source and destination.  Maybe try a different port number on parallel connections like 80 and 8080.

Comment: Hi @jdweng, what's strange is that the issue occurs rarely and randomly - I explain myself: when I run the test app, if the exception occurs the next calls still go through (it doesn't reoccur). At the same time, the call & content seems to be completed and received when it fails... I tried the different port trick but with no luck.

Comment: Do you think failure is occurring when two connection occur very close in time to each other?  This may be a known Core issue.  Does same happen if you use Net?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/3.1

Comment: sounds like @jdweng is right, you can probably avoid it by creating a new cookie container each time (which suck because you might have to reAuth) `var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{}`

Comment: you should build your own server to test this code, don't rely on some online test server because this could be caused by that server (not your code). And this error does seem look like so.

Comment: @jdweng @johnny yeah, I suspect it's related to close connections with heavy response stream; in the next days I'll be testing
1) @johnny solution on container cookie (in my appl. it would be okay, as each request has do to its own auth)
2) adding a using on ```await client.GetAsync()``` line (inspired by https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-5-new-networking-improvements/#comment-8363), as this could help to isolate each response object.
When I find a solution or something new I'll add it here :)

Comment: @KingKing test I'm doing happens on the real production/testing endpoint, the one I added in the post was a fake example - at the same time, a server issue you're guessing can be quite possible. I'll try the code on more endpoints next days, to find out if I can reproduce it on differents endpoints.

Comment: @followynne this code is trying to do the same thing a [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) does. It's far better to use the built-in class and clean up the code. Putting everything in the same file or the same method (the service running code) makes it harder to write and maintain the code, or isolate what's wrong.

Comment: @followynne what you try to do is essentially a [timed background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks) using `Task.Delay` in a loop instead of a timer. This means that only one request will be made each time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in my code (not the console app I shared for testing) the recurrent task is managed as a background service - the problem in my BackgroundService is that the DoWork method, run by the Timer, is the one who then runs the async multiple tasks calls.
Should I refactor it, as suggested per your last comment? As of now, that method is doing the same job as SendRequest() example, only using the timer and not the delay loop. How can or should I refactor it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: my StartAsync method of the background service:
`public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
      var firstRun = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, DateTime.UtcNow.Day, 03, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
      if (now > firstRun) firstRun = firstRun.AddDays(1);
      var ms = firstRun - now;
      if (ms <= TimeSpan.Zero) ms = TimeSpan.Zero;
      _timer = new Timer(SendRequest, null, ms, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));

      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my question to leave the solution I applied, for anyone who can encounter the same issue :)

I added the following line before the Api Call:

```
var client = _httpFactory.CreateClient();
var api = "https://api.npoint.io/5896085b486eed6483ce";

>>> client.DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version10; // new line

var res = await client.GetAsync(api);
```

The issue seems to be related to the endpoint server, that drops concurrent connections when the HttpVersion is 11. It's possible it relates to the Keep-Alive Connection header, since on 10 v. the header is set to Close.